# Problems with uploading multiple files in nodejs multer module

Tags: node.js, multer

MulterError: Unexpected field
at wrappedFileFilter (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
at Busboy. (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:196:13)
at Busboy.emit (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
at PartStream. (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:196:13)
at HeaderParser. (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:196:13)
at HeaderParser._finish (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
at SBMH. (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
at SBMH.emit (events.js:196:13)
at SBMH._sbmh_feed (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
at SBMH.push (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
at HeaderParser.push (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
at Dicer._oninfo (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
at SBMH. (/root/apps/embrerro/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)

Comment: It works well locally but in vps gives this error